# Error in get location windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, location, reverse-geocoding

I developing windows phone 8 application

I need to get the user current location city and state name on page load (Application start)

I tryed with following code

```
  public SplashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetCurrentCoordinate();
    }

  private async void GetCurrentCoordinate()
    {
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;

        try
        {
            Geoposition currentPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            _accuracy = currentPosition.Coordinate.Accuracy;

            MyCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(currentPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, currentPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);

            if (MyReverseGeocodeQuery == null || !MyReverseGeocodeQuery.IsBusy)
            {
                MyReverseGeocodeQuery = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
                MyReverseGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(MyCoordinate.Latitude, MyCoordinate.Longitude);
                MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryCompleted += MyReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted;
                MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }


 private void MyReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services.MapLocation>> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Result.Count > 0)
            {
                MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
                CurrentLocTextBlock.Text = "Current Location: " + address.City + ", " + address.State;
            }
        }
    }
```

if i run the above code it's come to try block and not move to next line

```
MyCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(currentPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, currentPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);"
```

some times code move to next line and result come. but most of time it's not go to next line.

how to overcome this. why this problem occur?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a timeout procedure by your self.

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();

// get the async task
var asyncResult = geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
var task = asyncResult.AsTask();

// add a race condition - task vs timeout task
var readyTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(10000));
if (readyTask != task) // timeout wins
    throw new TimeoutException();

// position found within timeout
var pos = await task;
return pos;
```

Refered from [GEOLOCATOR.GETGEOPOSITIONASYNC WITH CORRECT TIMEOUT](http://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/geolocator-getgeopositionasync-with-correct-timeout/)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a word "GeoCoordinate" at the beginning of current line

```
GeoCoordinate MyCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get your current position (GeoCoordinate), do this:

```
    private void findAddress(GeoCoordinate myCoordinate)
    {
        if (reverseGeocode != null) reverseGeocode = null;
        reverseGeocode = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
        reverseGeocode.GeoCoordinate = myCoordinate;
        reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted += reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted;
        reverseGeocode.QueryAsync();
    }
    void reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null && e.Result.Count > 0)
        {
            //Here you got all information about your current coordinate/position
            MapAddress myPositionAddress = null;
            myPositionAddress = e.Result.FirstOrDefault().Information.Address;
        }
    }
```